# Dimensionality mismatch for custom holidays in the Robyn model

Tags: r

I am trying to build a market mix model with the number of subscribers acquired as the target variable. I am using Robyn from Meta in R to do this. In the Robyn model, we have an option to include dt_prophet_holidays in the dt_holidays parameter as Robyn inputs. I want to use a custom holidays data frame in the dt_holidays parameter. I made sure that all the columns and values in the holidays data frame is same as in the dt_prophet_holidays data frame, including the datatypes of each column. But I am getting a dimension mismatch error. What should I do? How can I include my custom holidays data frame in the Robyn model in R?

```
InputCollect <- robyn_inputs(
  dt_input = clean_data,
  dt_holidays = dt_prophet_holidays,
  date_var = "trans_dt",
  dep_var = "non_ar",
  dep_var_type = "conversion",
  prophet_country = "US",
  prophet_vars = c("trend", "season", "holiday"),
  paid_media_vars = c("impressions_all_other_sites","impressions_bing_sem",
                      "impressions_dbm","impressions_facebook",
                      "impressions_google_sem","impressions_instagram"),
  paid_media_spends = c("paid_spend_all_other_sites","paid_spend_bing_sem",
                        "paid_spend_dbm","paid_spend_facebook",
                        "paid_spend_google_sem","paid_spend_instagram"),
  adstock = "weibull_pdf",
  window_start = "2016-01-01",
  window_end = "2023-12-31",
  
)
print(InputCollect)

hyper_names(adstock = InputCollect$adstock, all_media = InputCollect$all_media)

plot_adstock(plot = TRUE)
plot_saturation(plot = TRUE)

# Specify hyperparameters ranges for weibull_cdf adstock
hyperparameters <- list(
  paid_spend_all_other_sites_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_all_other_sites_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_all_other_sites_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_all_other_sites_shapes = c(0, 10),
  
  paid_spend_bing_sem_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_bing_sem_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_bing_sem_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_bing_sem_shapes = c(0, 10),
  
  paid_spend_dbm_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_dbm_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_dbm_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_dbm_shapes = c(0, 10),
  
  paid_spend_facebook_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_facebook_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_facebook_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_facebook_shapes = c(0, 10),
  
  paid_spend_google_sem_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_google_sem_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_google_sem_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_google_sem_shapes = c(0, 10),
  
  paid_spend_instagram_alphas = c(0.5, 3),
  paid_spend_instagram_gammas = c(0.3, 1),
  paid_spend_instagram_scales = c(0, 0.1),
  paid_spend_instagram_shapes = c(0, 10),

  train_size = c(0.5, 0.8)
)

#Add hyperparameters into robyn_inputs()
InputCollect <- robyn_inputs(InputCollect = InputCollect, hyperparameters = hyperparameters)
```

[image]

I tried to make a custom holidays dataframe with the columns, ds, holiday, country, year same as in the dt_prophet_holidays. I expected it to use the custom holidays without any error. But got a dimesnionality mismatch error.